# What is the fastest way to do a matrix exponential

Tags: python, matrix, julia, linear-algebra, exponential

I need to calculate the matrix exponential (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) for matrices of size upto 1000*1000.
As of now, in python, scipy.linalg.expm (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html) has been the fastest option for me. I have tried armadillo (https://arma.sourceforge.net/) in C++  and FastExpm (https://juliapackages.com/p/fastexpm) and ExponentialUtilities (https://docs.sciml.ai/ExponentialUtilities/stable/) in Julia. All of them have turned out to be slower than scipy.linalg.expm.

Is that really the fastest way to do it? Does anyone know of a better option?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that you often don't want the matrix exponential, and instead want `exp(A)*v` in which case you can get the result a lot faster with krylov methods. You also might want to try Julia's `exp` with the MKL package.

Comment: Actually, I want M*expm(A), where I right multiply the matrix exponential of A with the matrix M. Do you know any specific thing for it?